# Firebase : Fatal error index out of range : While updating the data little more faster then app going to crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Here I used Boolean Value to select the members by checkMark
once I touch the Name in the TableView is boolean value is updated to true and going to be check the Name.

Everything going right if  I increase the touching speed the App its going to crash and error came as **Fatal error index out of range**
Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions
I attached the screenshot of the application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46YcL.png)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if index == 0 {
        db.collection(dates!).document("members").collection("TodayMembers").whereField("name",isEqualTo: vechile[indexPath.row].cars).getDocuments { Snap, error in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                for i in Snap!.documents{
                    var checked = i.get("check") as! Bool
                    checked = !checked
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        i.reference.updateData(["check":checked])
                        self.vechileLoad()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Find out how to unwrap an optional value in Swift.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you for your suggestions. Now I solved that issue. Thank you...!